# Android giving errors

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout

I had an application running well, i dont know what happened now I am getting this log.. I am new to Android and it's hard for me to catch.. where it is faulting.. can you tell something by this log? thank you

```
04-24 04:09:29.561: WARN/ActivityManager(61):   Force finishing activity com.gaming.game/.GameActivity
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): ANR in com.gaming.game (com.gaming.game/.GameActivity)
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): Parent: com.gaming.game/.gaming
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): Load: 0.86 / 0.54 / 0.41
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): CPU usage from 48945ms to 2842ms ago:
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   9.2% 61/system_server: 6.9% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 1381 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   1.2% 672/com.android.launcher: 0.6% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 368 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0.6% 448/com.android.defcontainer: 0.1% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 56 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   1% 41/adbd: 0.1% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 64 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0.3% 125/com.android.systemui: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0.2% 123/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 2 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0% 587/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0% 35/installd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0% 120/jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0% 313/com.android.quicksearchbox: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0% 4/events/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0% 32/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0% 33/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 18 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0% 499/com.svox.pico: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 18 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):  +0% 1565/com.gaming.game: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): 31% TOTAL: 19% user + 11% kernel + 0% irq + 0.2% softirq
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): CPU usage from 796ms to 1401ms later:
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   43% 1565/com.gaming.game: 0% user + 43% kernel / faults: 1 minor
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):     43% 1567/HeapWorker: 0% user + 43% kernel
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   10% 61/system_server: 6.6% user + 3.3% kernel
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):     10% 100/InputDispatcher: 6.6% user + 3.3% kernel
04-24 04:47:55.491: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): 76% TOTAL: 4.6% user + 72% kernel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERROR/ActivityManager(61): ANR in com.gaming.game (com.gaming.game/.GameActivity)
Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut 04-24 04:47:55.491:

Your activity is taking too long to respond as is being killed.

Take a look at this post: http://danbarnett.net/android-anr-keydispatchingtimedout-178.html

> This ANR, or Application Not
>   Responding, error occurs when a
>   process on the main thread takes too
>   long (something like 5 seconds).
>   Android kills that process and any
>   related by design to spare the
>   device's resources.
>
> The solution is to run
>   resource-expensive tasks on another
>   thread, and then post, or update the
>   main thread accordingly. A common use
>   for this is network calls (and this
>   was what my problem was). The
>   following is an example of how to
>   implement this logic, in my case to
>   check if an update is needed:

Answer (score 1):

ANR means your application is not being responsive. I.e. you're doing an expensive operation (what, we cannot tell without your code) that is locking up the UI thread. Try kicking off some AsyncTasks or using a service for your long running operations.

Answer (score 0):

try to add some sleep time after you set bitmap to the canvas and before you add other things on top of it. It helped me